# What should be the etc/network/interfaces to set a static IP address?

Tags: static-ip

I try to set a static IP address (192.168.2.1)

here the output of `ifconfig`

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c8:1f:66:06:94:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 36920  bytes 133557122 (133.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 36920  bytes 133557122 (133.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx4c0fc7f11daf: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8955:c94:4868:c112  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:0f:c7:f1:1d:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21101  bytes 26754759 (26.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11273  bytes 1150027 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I use the wifi dongle to connect :

```
wlx4c0fc7f11daf: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8955:c94:4868:c112  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:0f:c7:f1:1d:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21101  bytes 26754759 (26.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11273  bytes 1150027 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My question is : what should I add to ´etc/network/interfaces ´  ?

The actual content is :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: I think the correct address is some file under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`...

Answer (score 2):

Append the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` to assign a static address to enp3s0 device:

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway <your-router-ip-address-goes-here>
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thaks , should I restart  something ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to restart networking to apply the changes. `systemctl restart networking`